# current working directory mismatch in python

Tags: python, getcwd

I have imported a existing filesystem folder as the new project folder in eclipse. I have a script which get the current working directory path of the code. I need to change directory location to acccess files in other directory related to it. But It is giving different value when executed from eclipse and from the command line. Location is same in both place. Please help me resolve this issue. Operating system is windows here

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))
print os.getcwd()
```

One result is this

```
C:\Automation\trunk\Base\TestScripts
C:\Automation\trunk\Base
```

Other result is this

```
C:\Automation\trunk\UsefulScripts
C:\Automation\trunk
```

Second result is the one I expect, and that is where the code is located exactly.

Comment: Please provide the different results that you get. Please specify with which OS you work, as all functions are not available on all OSs.

Comment: When your code runs in eclipse you have a certain amount of environment variables including ECLIPSE_HOME, PARENT_LOC, PROJECT_LOC and WORKSPACE_LOC. Use them to build your Path. You cannot rely on getcwd() when running in eclipse. On the command line you can. Just check for existense of these variables. If present use them if not ... use getcwd()

Comment: @Lescurel, i have provided those info.

Comment: @mbieren, I believe the code should be generic to run in both. how should attain that.

Comment: of course. I mean you have to code this in your function like `loc = os.environ.get('PROJECT_LOC',None)`. If loc is none use getcwd otherwise use loc as basedir for your UsefulScripts

Comment: i wonder, how would i know through which way , user will be running the code. how could i identify whether its eclipse or command line ? @mbieren

Comment: ok i will try that too @mbieren. Thank you so much

Comment: Thanks a lot @Lescurel

Answer (score 0):

watch out you cannot rely on that. Do the following :

```
basedir = os.environ.get('PROJECT_LOC', None)

if not basedir:
     basedir = sys.path[0]    # We are on commandline. sys.path OK
```

Then use basedir to find your files

**Update**

you have to specify this variable in the runtime of the interpreter

window->preferences->PyDev->Interpreters->Python Interpreter TAB (environment) There you can specify PROJECT_LOC referring to project_loc by selecting NEW with name PROJECT_LOC and variable (the other button) and selecting project_loc.

For some reasons those variables are not visible in python.

You can check this now with

```
def read_all_variables():
    for key in os.environ.keys():
        print ("%30s %s" % (key,os.environ[key]))
```

PROJECT_LOC should be there now

Comment: Is this PROJECT_LOC be set by eclipse itself ?

Comment: yes it is. If it is set you are sure that you are running in eclipse

Comment: That's nice. Good i learnt this today. i always thought getcwd will give correct result. Thanks a lot mbieren

Comment: getcwd() or sys.path[0] could be anything eg. cwd of the eclipse-process or the starting process .. whatever

Comment: code is getting inside that if block and always get the sys.path even when i ran from eclipse. Why is it so ?

Comment: basedir = os.environ.get(&#39;PROJECT_LOC&#39;, None) 
if not basedir: 
    basedir = sys.path[0] 
    print basedir
Always this if block is executed. And sys.path value is set even when I ran  from eclipse because project_loc is always none.

Comment: see my other anwer

Comment: Ok i will try that and let you know mbieren

Comment: sorry about this. I used these variables a hundred times but only with ant and java. That they are not visible with PyDev is also new to me

Comment: Strange!! ok mbieren. Let&#39;s find some other method. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

I have used the sys package instead of os. It works as expected.

```
import os,sys
currentpath = sys.path[0]
print currentpath
```

I can able to run it from eclipse and also from command line to get the correct path. Thanks for the help .

Comment: That isn't [what `sys.path` does](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path)!

Comment: It was working for me as expected. Can you please eloborate what it is for ? @ChristianTernus

Comment: Check out the link I posted. `sys.path` shows the Python path (where the interpreter searches for modules), not the OS current working directory.